# Silverlight ScrollViewer, Find if vertical Scrolling is enable

Tags: silverlight, scrollviewer

I have a Scroll viewer

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="sViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
```

Now after load, how can I find if the scroll Viewer is scroll-able vertically. i.e. is the Vertical Scrollbars are visible or Collapsed.

I tried to read Visibility property,

```
ScrollBar verticalScrollBar = ((FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(sViewer, 0)).FindName("VerticalScrollBar") as ScrollBar;
```

but every time i get Visibility as Collapsed, even when the Scrolling is available.

Will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ScrollBar.ScrollableHeight and ScrollBar.ScrollableWidth.  Value > 0 means that there are scroll bars.

You can also use ScrollViewer.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility and ScrollViewer.ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy, That worked.. only after I try to get those values after the render was completed.